# Output buffering and calling ECHO on an HTML string also containing ECHO

Tags: php, output-buffering

I have a template file that contains html with inlined PHP echo statements. For example, the template may look like:

```
<div class="<?php echo $classes ?>">

    <div class="uk-container uk-container-center">

        <section class="uk-grid uk-grid-match" data-uk-grid-match="{target:'> div > .uk-panel'}" data-uk-grid-margin>

            <?php echo $content ?>

        </section>

    </div>

</div>
```

The template is read in the script using file_get_contents(). I then turn on output buffering. The variables `$classes` and `$content` are in scope at the time ob_start() is called.

```
ob_start();

echo $htmlTemplateString;

$resolvedMarkup = ob_get_clean();
```

Unfortunately, $resolvedMarkup contains the original string read from the template file and the inlined echo statements are still present and not resolved to the values of the referenced variables.

My question is, am I interpreting this usage correctly? Should I be getting back a fully resolved string?

Normally, I could use `include` to achieve this sort of thing but on this occasion, despite the brevity of the example code, there are numerous reasons why the templates are brought into memory (mostly because each template may be in a hierarchy of templates that need to be resolved into each other, altering the original template structure).

At this stage, I am trying to avoid using temporary files.

I hope this question is clear and would appreciate any advice/thoughts as to whether my approach should work and if so, what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: `am I interpreting this usage correctly?` no `Should I be getting back a fully resolved string?` no

Comment: to execute php code you need to include this file

Comment: Thanks for answering my question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

> The template is read in the script using file_get_contents().

`file_get_contents()` is pretty much the equivalent of `fopen(); fread(); fclose()`. It simply sucks bytes from a file into a variable. Those bytes are NOT executed, so any PHP code blocks which maybe in that file remain as `<`, `?`, `p`, etc... characters - they're not executed/replaced.

You need to use `include()` instead. That will execute any PHP code in the byte stream.

Comment: I need to manipulate the template file content on certain occasions before the variables are resolved. My use of ```file_get_contents()``` is to get the file as a string, and not to resolve the variables at the point the file is read into memory. As the file content will be altered, short of creating a temporary file, I can't use ```include```.

Comment: Looks like the way to go. I appreciate your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Just echo does not actually parse any PHP. What you need is `eval`.
Here I have to convert my template into text that can be parsed by php.

```
<?php
$str1 = " this is <?php echo \$i;?> now\n";
$i=99;
echo eval('?>' . $str1 . '<?php ');
```

Comment: I had thought of ```eval``` but was trying to avoid its use. However, it's looking like it may be a solution given that I don't want to create temporary files so that they can be "included".